# Typecasting error in sessions in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp file adminLogin.jsp where i check the session attributes passed on from index.jsp and from logout.jsp :

```
<%
      String s=(String)session.getAttribute("wrongP");
    if(s.equals('0'))
    {out.println("Wrong Details or you logged out Please Login Again <br>");
    session.invalidate();
    }

    %>
    This is login 

form
    <br>Please login<br>

            <form method="GET" action="login1">
             <br>.           Id:<input type="text" name="id"><br>Password:<input
                    type="password" name="pass"><br> <input type="submit"
                    value="Submit">
            </form>
            </div>
```

The error i am getting is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /adminLogin.jsp at line 12
```

---

> type Exception report
>
> ```
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page /adminLogin.jsp at line 12
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception 
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /adminLogin.jsp at line 12
>
> 9: <body>
> 10: <div align="center">
> 11: <%
> 12: String s=(String)session.getAttribute("wrongP");
> 13: if(s.equals('0'))
> 14: {out.println("Wrong Details or you logged out Please Login Again <br>");
> 15: session.invalidate();
>
>
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
>
> root cause 
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>   org.apache.jsp.adminLogin_jsp._jspService(adminLogin_jsp.java:72)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 logs.
> ```

I type casted the attribute but i am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type casting using `(String) Object` can only type cast an object
>   of type `String`.

If its not a String object then it will generate an error..
Better Method is to use

```
String.valueOf(object);
```

Here in your case it will surely generate an error if the `session.getAttribute("wrongP")` returns an instance of object other than String.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `session.getAttribute("wrongP")` returning a `char` and you tries to cast it to `String`, that's why you are getting `ClassCastException`.

You have to use [`String.valueOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29) to cast your `char` value into `String`:

```
String str = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("wrongP"));
```

**One more thing :**

after getting `String`, in your `if` condition, you are comparing the `String` object with `char` value `if(s.equals('0'))`.

You have to do this like :

```
if(s.equals("0"))
```

> **Note:** Try to do minimum java code in your jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

Your message tells you what the problem is: `java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

So the value of that attribute is of type `Character` and thus casting that to `String` of course will fail.

`String.valueOf(...)` would help, but keep in mind that the result depends on the actual type, e.g. if the attribute was a string array, it would not work.

Addtionally, `if(s.equals('0'))` would not work, since a string and character (which you get using the literal notation `'0'`) are *not equal*.

In your case use one of the following:

Id' prefer this because there's no cast:

```
String s=String.valueOf( session.getAttribute("wrongP") );
if(s.equals("0")) {  //use a String here
  ...
}
```

This should work as well, but would have the risk of another `ClassCastException` it the type of the attribute changes:

```
Character c=(Character)session.getAttribute("wrongP");
if(s.equals('0')) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have stored in `session.setAttribute("attributeName",attributeValue)` is not able to convert in `String`.